# How to create a simple textarea without ng-Model in angular.js?

Tags: angularjs, input, binding

In my angular.js app, I have a textarea like this:

`<textarea ng-model='model.content'>{{model.content}}</textarea>`.

The user edits the content in the textarea and then clicks a button, at which point I record the current (previous) value of model.content, and then update it with the current text of textarea.

However, textarea immediately updates model.content as soon as its onchange event fires (because it's a 2-way binding), and by the time the button is clicked, model.content already contains the text of textarea, and I have no record of the previous value of model.content.

Question – how do I stop angular from updating the model? I don't want the model updated until the button is clicked. As you see I don't need a two-way binding at all. However, ng-model is required for the textarea directive. I've tried creating a custom directive but angular still treats any textarea tag as a directive requiring a two-way binding instead of an unknown html tag.

Comment: actually updates model on every keystroke, paste etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `angular.copy()` utility that clones (makes copy) of the model and creates new instance.

See Docs <kbd>[HERE](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.copy)</kbd>

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="fessCntrl">
    <div class="text-area-container">
        <textarea   rows="2" ng-model="textModel"></textarea>
    </div>

    <button ng-click="commit(textModel);">Commit</button>

    <pre>copy: {{copy|json}}</pre>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var fessmodule = angular.module('myModule', []);

fessmodule.controller('fessCntrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.copy = '';

    $scope.commit = function (textModel) {
        $scope.copy = angular.copy(textModel);
    };
});
fessmodule.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/835/)**</kbd>

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you for such a prompt fix. I just added ng-init: `<textarea ng-model='temp' ng-init='temp=model.content'>{{temp}}</textarea>` to initialize the textarea with the value I needed. Works pretty much like a one-way binding. (I wish I could upvote your answer)

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it backward. Instead of trying to save the original content when the user has finished editing the value (and the original content is thus already modified), you should save it *before* he does it, when the model is populated and the page displayed.

Also, you don't need `{{model.content}}`inside the textarea.

Comment: The problem is, the model would still get updated if the user just edits the textarea and doesn't click the button...

Comment: Yes, but it's not a problem since you made a backup copy. You can of course also choose to bind the textarea to the copy and leave the model unmodified. The important thing is to have a value in the scope that contains the original value, and another, bound to the textarea, containing the modified value.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a two way binding yourself.

You will keep a local variable `localContent` which will hold the content of the `textarea`. Then set up a callback on the button which will set `model.content = localContent`. 
Further, set up a `$watch` on the actual `model.content` and update `localContent` when the original model changes.